# How to redirect wordpress (installed inner directory) to main root address?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've installed wordpress into a inner directory. like `root/mysite` . Why I didn't install it on root because there are so many addon domain installed, and I literally don't want to mess all addon domain folders with wordpress files inside root directory. My root directory is for `www.example.com` . And my wordpress site I've installed on `root/mysite`, so the url for that is `www.example.com/mysites` . Is there anyway to redirect `www.example.com/mysites` to `www.example.com` . As I said the only reason for not installing wordpress on my root, because I don't want to mess wordpress files, folders with other addon domain's folders on root.

So my main goal is showing a wordpress site on `www.jimfahad.com` that is installed on `www.example.com/mysites`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can leave the WordPress install and folders in `mysites`, but you have to copy the `.htaccess`file and the `index.php` file to root. This will result in the visual URL of WordPress being in root `(example.com)`, but the uploads, theme URLs, etc, being in `example.com/mysites`.

See the [WordPress Codex > Giving WordPress Its Own Directory « Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) on how to copy and edit the files:

> 1) Go to the General settings panel.
>
> 2) In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root
>   directory's URL. Example: `http://example.com`
>
> 3) Click Save Changes. (Do not worry about the error message and do
>   not try to see your blog at this point! You will probably get a
>   message about file not found.)
>
> 4) Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the
>   WordPress (wordpress in our example) directory into the root directory
>   of your site—the latter is probably named something like www or
>   public_html. The .htaccess file is invisible, so you may have to set
>   your FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty
>   permalinks, then you may not have a .htaccess file. If you are running
>   WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server and are using pretty permalinks,
>   you'll have a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in your
>   WordPress directory.
>
> 5) Edit your root directory's index.php:
>
> 6) Open your root directory's index.php file in a text editor. Change
>   the line that says:
>
> `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`
>
> to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core
>   files:
>
> `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
>
> and save the file.
>
> 7) Login to your site (if you aren't still already). The URL should
>   still be `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/`
>
> 8) If you have set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks panel and
>   update your Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically update
>   your .htaccess file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If
>   WordPress can't write to your .htaccess file, it will display the new
>   rewrite rules to you, which you should manually copy into your
>   .htaccess file (in the same directory as the main index.php file.)