# Installing wordpress in a different directory than root because another CMS is installed there

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a weird situation with a client:

The root directory has a custom built CMS serving the site.
They want to rebuild the site in stages as it is very big.
So they want the new site in Wordpress and for the first stage just to build specific pages in Wordpress.
So obviously I would install WP in a sub directory or a different directory than root.
BUT, they want the pages served by WP to not indicate a different URL path so if we create a page called page1 the URL needs to be:
http://domainname.com/page1 not 
http://domainname.com/wp/page1

Obviously if a browser navigates to:
http://domainname.com/page1
the CMS installed in root will try to serve the page and return a 404.

So my thinking is it must be possible to add a bunch of rules in the root folder htaccess (or with PHP) that check a list if the incoming request is for a URL we indicated in the list is meant to be served from WP, then to pull the files from the WP sub directory (bypassing the CMS installed in root) and rewrite the URL to root.

So if I go with my browser to:
http://domainname.com/page1
I will get the WP page
and if I go with the browser to:
http://domainname.com/wp/page1
it will server that page but with a 301 redirect to:
http://domainname.com/page1

Makes sense? Anyone know if this is possible?
I have tried but my htaccess/apache skills are not high enough to solve this one.

Thanks

Comment: Create they a lot of new pages in the Custom CMS?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but if you are asking if the custom CMS has a lot of pages then yes, it has hundreds of pages and that is why we don't want to remove it yet but only rebuild and serve important ones with WP.

Comment: I think the best solution is to rewrite everything to the wp folder except all the current URL's.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to do this? I mean the part that makes it load wordpress if it is not one of those URL's...
I think without editing index.php and htaccess in root it won't work see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041363/how-to-redirect-wordpress-installed-inner-directory-to-main-root-address?rq=1

Comment: What is the current .htaccess from the custom built CMS?

Comment: I can't paste it here for security reasons but it is mainly 301 redirects, handling expiry for assets and what looks like a redirect for when accessing cpanel.

And then at the end there is this which is weird because WP is not installed in root:

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You are in a very complicated position, in one way that could be very easy if your client doesn't bother with the subfolder which is pretty reasonable and cheaper because you don't have to spend time trying figure out how to get a clean URL, instead of that you can have a semantic URL like: 
http://domainname.com/page/page1
So you have your Wordpress installation in the "page" folder and everything looks transparent for the user.

On the other hand, if you what create re-directions for each page you create in the new Wordpress you can do it in the Cpanel if you have access to the server.

The problem is you have to do after a new page publication.

In terms of SEO, you are getting a Soft bounce, which is not terrible but not terrific.

when you migrate all the content to Wordpress you have to delete all those redirections and will be more work to do in terms of SEO

The bottom line is if you have enough arguments for why you client could let you do it in the easy way that can help you a lot and save a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks, yes I explained this to them and they still want to find a way to hide the subfolder from the URL.
I think managing redirects for new pages is acceptable for them as it is temporary until everything will move to WP.
Do you know how to make this work? Like what is the code in PHP or in the htaccess meant to look like?

Comment: If you have access to the cPanel, there is something called redirecciones and I think that is the easier way to do this.